# Multiple variables in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
          else
    {
        r=Power(s,n-1);
        System.out.println(r);
        int d=r.length;
        char ch=s.charAt(n);
        int v=d+1;
        p[v]=Character.toString(ch);
        String q = p[v];

        for(i=d+2,j=0;i<2d+3,j<d;i++,j++)
        {
            p[i]=r[j].concat(q);
        }
}
```

A syntax error is shown and var j is not recognized even after declaration... pls help me.

Comment: If a syntax error is shown, then your program cannot run at all. You need to fix the syntax error first.

Comment: I don't see the declaration of `j`; Just place an `int j;` before the `for` loop

Comment: by the way, `i` seems to not have been declared either. you might need to change `i=d+2` to `int i=d+2`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is the condition of the loop. The correct should be:

```
for(i=d+2,j=0;i<2d+3 && j<d;i++,j++){ ...
```

or

```
for(i=d+2,j=0;i<2d+3 || j<d;i++,j++){ ...
```

There is no meaning in putting a comma separating two boolean conditions in java.

And as seen in the comments, variables `j` and `i` are not declared.

Comment: Good catch! I can't remember if Java was like C regarding the comma operator, where `cond1, cond2` would yield the same result as writing `cond2`(assuming `cond1` has no side-effects, of course, like in this case).